# Android RecyclerView using VideoView in ViewHolder

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I want to play video using `RecyclerView` and using `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition()` scroll page.

When `RecyclerView` using `VideoView` in `ViewHolder`, `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, position)` position can't match `RecyclerView` current position, so I can't control VideoView.

Adapter:

```
interface Control {
    int getCurrentPosition() ;
}

Control control;

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder()...page: " + control.getCurrentPosition() );
}

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, position){
    Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder()...position: " + position + ", page: " + control.getCurrentPosition() );

    int page = control.getCurrentPosition();

    // position maybe difference page value
}
```

Activity:

```
int page;

void onCreate() {
    adapter = new Adapter(new Adapter.Control() {
            @Override
            public int getCurrentPosition() {
                return page;
            }
        });
}

void scroll() {
    Log.i(TAG, "page: " + page );
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(page);
}
```

Log:

```
page: 0
onCreateViewHolder()...page: 0
onBindViewHolder()...position: 0, page: 0

page: 1
onCreateViewHolder()...page: 1
onBindViewHolder()...position: 1, page: 1
onCreateViewHolder()...page: 1
onBindViewHolder()...position: 2, page: 1

page: 2
onCreateViewHolder()...page: 2
onBindViewHolder()...position: 3, page: 2

page: 3
page: 4
onBindViewHolder()...position: 4, page: 4
onBindViewHolder()...position: 5, page: 4

page: 5
page: 6
onBindViewHolder()...position: 6, page: 6
onBindViewHolder()...position: 7, page: 6

page: 7
page: 8
onBindViewHolder()...position: 8, page: 8
onBindViewHolder()...position: 9, page: 8

page: 9
```